# Need to count the number of operations in a 24 hour interval between dates in one column

Tags: python, pandas

My `df`, where `id` - id of member and `dp_id` - id of terminal:

```
    d = {'date': ['2020-11-14 01:22:10.260','2020-11-14 01:41:13.260',
              '2020-11-14 16:39:31.910','2020-11-14 23:39:52.510',
              '2020-11-14 00:00:00.260','2020-11-15 00:01:20.710',
              '2020-11-15 01:00:43.600','2020-11-15 13:41:19.410'],
     'id': [300000,352575,352575,352575,300000,352575,352575,352575],
     'dp_id':['002','001','001','001','002','001','001','001']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    date                     id      dp_id
  0 2020-11-14 01:22:10.260  300000  002    
  1 2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575  001
  2 2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575  001
  3 2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575  001
  4 2020-11-14 00:00:00.260  300000  002
  5 2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575  001
  6 2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575  001
  7 2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575  002
```

If the number of operations in next 24 hours from the first transaction of the day for pair `id` - `dp_id` (`352575` - `001`) is more than 4, it should be marked as `over_lim`.

For example, if the first operation for `id`-`dp_id` was at `01: 41: 13.260`, therefore, over the next 24 hours, i need to count how many operations were there and mark each transaction if there were more than 4 in 24 hours.

i.e. `4 2020-11-15 01: 00: 43.600 352575 001` operation will be the 5th operation in 24 hours from the the first transaction of the day by `id`-`dp_id`, therefore we mark it as `over_lim`. And so on for each day - we need to take the first transaction of the day and see how much it was in the next 24 hours.

Expected output table, where `tr_count` - count of each transaction per pair `id`-`dp_id`, `over_lim`- our mark, that it's a overlimit transaction(>=5):

```
  date                     id      dp_id tr_count over_lim
0 2020-11-14 01:22:10.260  300000  002   1        False
1 2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575  001   1        False
2 2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575  001   2        False
3 2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575  001   3        False
4 2020-11-14 00:00:00.260  300000  002   1        False
5 2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575  001   4        False
6 2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575  001   5        True
7 2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575  002   1        False
```

UPD:
got this instead:

```
   date      id dp_id  tr_count  over_lim
 0 2020-11-14 01:22:10.260  300000   002         1     False
 1 2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575   001         1     False
 2 2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575   001         2     False
 3 2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575   001         3     False
 4 2020-11-14 00:00:00.260  300000   002         2     False
 5 2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575   001         1     False
 6 2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575   001         2     False
 7 2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575   001         3     False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group by 24 hours span and then use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['tr_count'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='24h', origin='start'), 'id', 'dp_id']).cumcount() + 1
df['over_lim'] = df['tr_count'] > 4

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                     date      id  dp_id  tr_count  over_lim
0 2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575      1         1     False
1 2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575      1         2     False
2 2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575      1         3     False
3 2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575      1         4     False
4 2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575      1         5      True
5 2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575      2         1     False
```

Note that you must use `origin='start'`, from the documentation:

> ‘start’: origin is the first value of the timeseries

**UPDATE**

For the new data, you can do:

```
def grouper(x):
    d = x.rename('date').to_frame().reset_index()
    return d.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='24h', origin='start')).cumcount() + 1


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['tr_count'] = df.groupby(['id', 'dp_id'])['date'].transform(grouper)
df['over_lim'] = df['tr_count'] > 4

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                     date      id dp_id  tr_count  over_lim
0 2020-11-14 01:22:10.260  300000   002         1     False
1 2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575   001         1     False
2 2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575   001         2     False
3 2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575   001         3     False
4 2020-11-14 00:00:00.260  300000   002         2     False
5 2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575   001         4     False
6 2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575   001         5      True
7 2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575   001         1     False
```

Comment: Seems like it's work perfect. Testing on a much bigger df now. Thank you!

Comment: but what if there are different start of timeseries for each group? Updated my code< add one more string with another pair of id-cat_id

Comment: Now it's updated, i added one more transaction of another pair of id-dp_id. I cannot adapt your code for this case, when one pair can be interrupted by another one

Comment: @rzhekic I ran the code on this new input and is returning the expected output, is the output correct?

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, added UPD title, output is correct, try one more time pls with new input

Comment: @rzhekic Try now :)